# Filter processes by name and nice number

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, nice

I'm trying to create a script to find the PID number with only the process name and nice number, but I'm not able to.

Comment: What script? Read `man pgrep proc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
by_name_and_nice(){ grep -hoPs "^[^ ]+(?= \($1\)( [^ )]+){16} $2 )" /proc/*/stat; }
```

`by_name_and_nice bash 0` will find all `bash` processes with their niceness = 0 (the default),

`by_name_and_nice 'b.*' '.*'` will find all processes with their name starting with a `b`, no matter their niceness, and so on.

If you the above to also get processes with newlines and binary garbage in their names, you may need something a bit more convoluted:

```
by_name_and_nice(){
    local -; set -o pipefail
    LC_ALL=C grep -zhoPs "^[^ ]+(?= \($1\)( [^ )]+){16} $2 )" /proc/*/stat | xargs -0rn1
}
```

To match a newline in the process name, you should use `by_name_and_nice '(?s:foo.*)' 0` (go read about the [pcre regex syntax](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#TOC1) used by GNU grep's `-P` option).

---

This is only for demo purposes; it's pretty pointless to try to select by nice value without some greater-than or less-than operator. Also, selecting by process name is not very reliable, because the process name is under the total control of the process, which is ruthlessly abused by any two-bit malware and crapware to call themselves `ps` or `bash`. A better idea would be to select by the basename of the binary, as in

```
find /proc/*/exe -lname '*/whatever'
```

Developing all that is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: Better as `grep -zhoPs "^[^ ]+(?= \($1\)( [^ )]+){16} $2 [^)]*\Z)"` to avoid problems with process names that contain `)`s. The process name in `/proc/pid/stat` is the part between the first occurrence of `(` and the last occurrence of `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pgrep` to first get the PIDs of all processes matching the expression given as the first argument, and then looping through these to extract the ones that has a nice value corresponding to the second argument.

```bsh
find_pid_by_name_and_nice () {
    pgrep -- "${1:?missing process name}" |
    xargs -I {} ps -o pid= -o nice= -p {} |
    awk -v nice="${2?missing nice value}" '$NF == nice { print $1 }'
}
```

Testing:

```bsh
$ find_pid_by_name_and_nice
find_pid_by_name_and_nice:1: 1: missing process name
find_pid_by_name_and_nice:3: 2: missing nice value
```

```bsh
$ find_pid_by_name_and_nice netdata
find_pid_by_name_and_nice:3: 2: missing nice value
```

```bsh
$ find_pid_by_name_and_nice netdata 19
258881
258937
```

```bsh
$ find_pid_by_name_and_nice netdata 15
```

(no output)

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly, with `ps` and `awk`:

```
by_name_and_nice() {
  # returns pids of processes with $2 as niceness and whose
  # process name matches the $1 extended regexp
  ps -A -o pid= -o nice= -o comm= |
    NAME=$1 NICE=$2 awk '
      $2 == ENVIRON["NICE"] {
        pid = $1
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+ +[^[:space:]]+ /, "")
        if ($0 ~ ENVIRON["NAME"]) print pid
      }'
}
```

That assumes there's a single space character between the niceness column and the process name. That happens to be the case with the procps-ng implementation as typically found on Linux-based systems, but is not guaranteed by POSIX. You could strip all whitespace character after the niceness column, but that runs the risk of misrepresenting processes whose name starts with whitespace.

Note that procps-ng's `ps` at least changes non-printable characters to `?` in the output and what constitutes a non-printable character depends on the locale of the caller of `ps`. For instance, a process with UTF-8 `Stéphane` as name could be rendered as `St??phane` if the locale uses a different charset than UTF-8.

The `procps-ng` implementations of `ps` does support a `-C` option though to match processes on name (inspired from HP/UX' `ps`), though that's an exact byte-to-byte equality match instead of regular expression match, so you could do:

```
by_name_and_nice() {
  # returns pids of processes with $2 as niceness and whose
  # process name is exactly $1
  ps -C "$1" -o pid= -o nice= |
    awk -v nice="$2" '$2 == nice {print $1}'
}
```